# Jenkins pipeline - Getting the pipeline status in C#

Tags: c#, jenkins

I was able to kick off a Jenkins pipeline build by sending a post request (with username/password) to `Jenkins-Pipeline-URL/buildwithParameter`.

Is there a way inside the code to know which build I kicked off and also get the status of that build using some rest API?

Answer (score 3):

From the Jenkins API documentation:

> **Accessing Progressive Console Output**
>
> You can retrieve in-progress
> console output by making repeated GET requests with a parameter.
> You'll basically send GET request to this URL (or this URL if you want
> HTML that can be put into  tag.) The start parameter controls the
> byte offset of where you start.
>
> The response will contain a chunk of the console output, as well as
> the X-Text-Size header that represents the bytes offset (of the raw
> log file). This is the number you want to use as the start parameter
> for the next call.
>
> If the response also contains the X-More-Data: true header, the server
> is indicating that the build is in progress, and you need to repeat
> the request after some delay. The Jenkins UI waits 5 seconds before
> making the next call. When this header is not present, you know that
> you've retrieved all the data and the build is complete.

Your url will look something like:

`https://Jenkins-Pipeline-URL/lastBuild/logText/progressiveText?start=0`

Depending on what you plan to do with the status, you can either keep polling the entire logs, or you can increment the start counter as you read in text based on the number of characters read. This will give you new running output from the build.

Also from the documentation:

> `https://Jenkins-Pipeline-URL/lastBuild/buildNumber`
>
> This URL returns the build number in text/plain format.

If you only wish to obtain whether the build passed or failed:

`https://Jenkins-Pipeline-URL/lastBuild/api/json`

Will return json (or xml if *json* is replaced in the url) that can be parsed for the result object:

> "result":"SUCCESS"

You can create repeated GET requests, similar to the first answer, to get an updated status.

Comment: The problem is getting the lastBuild in  https://Jenkins-Pipeline-URL/lastBuild/api/json url.

I can access the list of builds from https://Jenkins-Pipeline-URL/api/json url, but how will I know which build did i kick off - It can happen that while my code was starting the job, another user also came in and kicked off another job

Comment: If that is a concern, you could add a "quiet period" to your builds (30 seconds for example). This ensures that builds can only be ran within the specified time frame of each other. If two builds are kicked off within 30 seconds of each other, the later will overwrite the former build. https://jenkins.io/blog/2010/08/11/quiet-period-feature

Comment: I could see the pipeline api working i.e. http://<machine-name>:8080/view/<pipeline>/api/json?pretty=true but I get a 404 for the lastBuild api mentioned here - http://<machine-name>:8080/view/<pipeline>/lastBuild/api/json?pretty=true. Is there anything I am missing? I am looking to get the current status of the pipeline.